# Reading and using OpenText's exported XML

Tags: opentext

We're working on a migration project to migrate OpenText content into another content management system.

We have been provided a sample exported Xml from OpenText but it's not very intuitive and we can't find any documentation or tools to help us get a document's fields and related content.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are talking about metadata file in xml format. If I am correct, each document object has a metadata file and xml file is named with object id of document.
If you open this file, you can see attributes are mapped with their corresponding values.

if it is so far so good, then we can convert these file in xls or write a parser using external API ( For Example, if working in java , I will prefer XPATH)